# SurfaceView is not showing play/pause/backward/forward icon with media player while playing video

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I am using media player and surface view to play video, but while playing video there is no icon to play or pause as we get with video view play or pause icon while playing video, is there any method which should i call to get these icon, or i have to place manually for surface view. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Media controller  along with your media player

by calling the setMedaiController method

Comment: mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
 mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder); Sorry but i am not getting any method like setmediacontroller

Comment: I am using code from Api demos from here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Comment: But my question is different as i am not getting media player controlling icon.

Comment: I got the solution used MediaPlayerControl for my activity, and created MediaController object show method.